# Select over multiple databases TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a single select statement I'd like to run against multiple databases simultaneously:

```
select LastName from TABLE where LastName like '%eloph'
```

All the databases I want to select from contain the same table, with identical structures, but there are over 300 of them. How can I avoid writing that same query 300 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just append the database name in front of the table name. If you want all the data returned as one result set then use `UNION ALL` to append the results

```
Select LastName from dbname1.dbo.TABLE where LastName like '%eloph'
UNION ALL 
Select LastName from dbname2.dbo.TABLE where LastName like '%eloph'
UNION ALL
Select LastName from dbname3.dbo.TABLE where LastName like '%eloph'
UNION ALL
Select LastName from dbname4.dbo.TABLE where LastName like '%eloph'
```

Keep adding Union all and select statements.

Or if you adverse to editing, this should generate most of what you need.

It will generate the sql for you, just copy it and remove the last UNION ALL

```
SELECT 'Select LastName from ' + name + '.dbo.TABLE where LastName like ''%eloph''
UNION ALL ' 
FROM sys.databases
```

Note the doubled single quotes

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's actually exactly what I'm hoping to avoid. I know the copy and paste necessary isn't difficult, but doing it 300 time is a bit tedious. Any way around it?

Comment: Well do you have  list of all the the databases some where?  If in a table you could write a select statement to create the query.

Comment: @paparazzo can you show an example, how could I write a select statement to create the query

Comment: @Sam11 the second example will generate the query that you need, just with an extra UNION ALL at the end. You just need to customise it